# systemd sd_notify service reload via SIGHUP

Tags: c, signals, daemon, systemd

I am implementing a systemd service that makes use of sd_notify.

In the [sd_notify documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html) it is state that such a service must send `sd_notify(0, "READY=1");` once reloading was completed.

This makes sense for reloads that have been triggered by the service itself, but I am wondering how this affects reloads triggered by the user (`systemctl reload`), because the [systemd.service documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecReload=) states that the reload command should be synchronous to wait for the reload to complete.

My question now is: Can I use an asynchronous command (like `/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID`) on a notify service and use `RELOADING=1` and `READY=1` to get a "blocking" reload, i.e. let systemd wait for my service, or does systemd ignore those two in case of a reload from systemctl?

And for completness: My code and what I want to have:

```
void doReload() {
    sd_notify(0, "RELOADING=1");
    // operation that takes ca 5 seconds
    sd_notify(0, "READY=1");
}
```

and this method can be called either from the code internally, or by the signal handler registered for `SIGHUP`

The relevant part from the systemd unit is:

```
[Service]
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=main
ExecStart=/usr/bin/testd
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
```

And I want to archive that `ExecReload` is done synchronously.

Comment: Gosh, 5 years, and nobody has answered yet?!... it's just that I do have the same question myself!

Answer (score 1):

Systemd 253 added a service type of [`notify-reload`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=):

> Behavior of notify-reload is identical to notify. However, it extends the logic in one way: the SIGHUP UNIX process signal is sent to the service's main process when the service is asked to reload. (The signal to send can be tweaked via ReloadSignal=, see below.) When initiating the reload process the service is then expected to reply with a notification message via sd_notify(3) that contains the "RELOADING=1" field in combination with "MONOTONIC_USEC=" set to the current monotonic time (i.e. CLOCK_MONOTONIC in clock_gettime(2)) in μs, formatted as decimal string. Once reloading is complete another notification message must be sent, containing "READY=1". Using this service type and implementing this reload protocol is an efficient alternative to providing an ExecReload= command for reloading of the service's configuration.

Example unit file:

```
[Service]
Type=notify-reload
NotifyAccess=main
ExecStart=/usr/bin/testd
# In case you want to use a signal other than SIGHUP for reloading:
#ReloadSignal=SIGUSR1
```

Example (error checking omitted):

```c
void doReload() {
    timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    sd_notifyf(0, "RELOADING=1\nMONOTONIC_USEC=%" PRIdMAX "%06d", (intmax_t)ts.tv_sec, (int)(ts.tv_nsec / 1000));
    // operation that takes ca 5 seconds
    sd_notify(0, "READY=1");
}
```